# How can I create and run a webhost inside my test-libary?

Tags: c#, testing, asp.net-core, nunit

I am currently working on a pretty simple test libary. The solution also contains an ASP.NET Core Webhost, which processes simple CRUD operations.
I want to unit test this ASP.NET Core application without always having to start both projects, so I am creating a new WebHostBuilder inside my NUNit test-libary.

```
[OneTimeSetUp]
public void SetupHost()
{
    var webhostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseContentRoot("root")
        .UseStartup(typeof(Startup))
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile("config1", false);
            config.AddJsonFile("config2", false);
        });

    webhostBuilder
        .Build()
        .Run();
}
```

The problem is that `SetupHost()` never finishes, because `Run()` blocks the thread until the host shuts down.

How can I start a new webhost, then after it successfully started start my unit tests?

Comment: You should actually hold on to the built host so you can shut it down after testing.

Comment: Don't build a web host at all. Use the test server. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @ChrisPratt The API is not a MVC application.

Comment: @MarcoSiffert: That doesn't matter. The test server works with any web host. While the samples use `Startup` as the generic type param, this corresponds simply to the entry point of the application. It could just as well be `Program` there. Not that `Startup` is bound to MVC, either. You can have a generic web host that still utilizes `Startup`. It's actually a good practice, regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Hold on to the [`IWebHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhost?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and use `Start` instead

```
IWebHost host;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void SetupHost() {
    var webhostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseContentRoot("root")
        .UseStartup(typeof(Startup))
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile("config1", false);
            config.AddJsonFile("config2", false);
        });

    host = webhostBuilder.Build();

    host.Start(); //Starts listening on the configured addresses.
}
```

Later, call [`StopAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhost.stopasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IWebHost_StopAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) to attempt to gracefully shut down the host.